# Azure SQL Databases Admin Permissions

Tags: sql-server, azure, security, azure-sql-database, rbac

We are looking at moving a number of applications from on prem SQL Servers upto Azure as a Paas offering, what would be the best way to grant the Database team access to these databases? They'll be under one tenant but spread across a couple of subscriptions and multiple resource groups.

Moving forward i'd also like for them to have permissions automatically for any new SQL database added to any resource group within our tenant.

Little bit confused on the best approach?

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: Would it be ok to grant them server admin permissions? You could assign them to an Azure AD group and make that group the Azure AD admin for each Azure SQL server. That way they can login using their AAD credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform below mentioned tasks to achieve your requirement.

- create an Azure Active Directory user
- create an Azure Active Directory group and assign the user group
- add an Azure Active Directory user/group as an Azure SQL
  Administrator
- add Azure Active Directory users to Azure SQL Database

Follow this third-party [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directory-usergroup-and-azure-sql-database/) to implement the same.

Additionally, you can have Database-level role for each user for more safety of the data. Please check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15) from Microsoft.